# Show that all numbers can be written as $x=k\alpha+x'$, given...

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

The question is: Suppose $\alpha>0$. Prove that any real number $x$ can be written uniquely in the form $x=k\alpha+x'$, where $k$ is an integer and $0\leq x'\lt\alpha$.

How do I approach this problem? Perhaps construct a set for all $x$ that cannot be expressed in this way and show that it is empty?

Comment: The word "numbers" should be identified a little more clearly I think...are you referring to integers? If it is then you are looking for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: it is sufficient to show that any real number can be written as a sum of its integer and "fractional" or "decimal" parts.